# Passing different content that implements the same interface

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, interface, polymorphism, covariance

I have multiple Linq2Sql Classes such as "Article" "NewsItem" "Product".

They all have a title, they all have a unique ID and they all have a Summary.

So, I created an interface called `IContent`

```
public interface IContent {
    int Id { get; set; }
    String Title { get; set; }
    String Summary { get; set; }
    String HyperLink { get; set; }
}
```

In my code, I'm trying to make it possible to pass a `List<T>` that implements `IContent` and then use those common properties that I have implemented in each of the partial classes in my project.

So, just to clarify

`Article` is a Linq Entity.
I create a partial class and implement `IContent` Here's a snippet of Article.cs:

```
   #region IContent Members

    public int Id {
        get {
            return this.ArticleID;
        }
        set {
            this.ArticleID = value;
        }
    }
```

Pretty Simple. In my code I'm trying to this, but I don't know where I'm going wrong:

```
List<IContent> items;

MyDataContext cms = new MyDataContext();

items = cms.GetArticles();  
// ERROR: Can not implicitly convert List<Article> to List<IContent>
```

If my `Article` class implement `IContent` why can't I pass in Articles? I don't know what the objects that are going to be passed in.

I know I can do this with Inheriting a base class, but using LinqToSQL doesn't use regular objects.

I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
items = cms.GetArticles().Cast<IContent>().ToList();
```

Comment: I think you were the first to state the need to `Cast`

Answer (score 7):

This is because the List class and interface aren't covariant. If you're using .NET 4.0 and C# 4.0, you can actually use covariance on the `IEnumerable<>` interface, which should be okay for LINQ applications.

[There's a good FAQ covering those topics.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/covariance-and-contravariance-faq)

Comment: So... if i passed an `IEnumerable<Article>` to an `IEnumerable<IContent>` it would work? I'm using .Net 3.5 so I'm guessing I'm hooped. I'm wondering what a good solution is.

Comment: Yes, that would work with 4.0. With 3.5, you can use the `Cast()` LINQ extension method.

Answer (score 1):

This is classic case that calls for co-variance in C# 4.0. You only have to change `List<Article>` to `IEnumerable<Article>` to make this assignemnt work:

```
IEnumerable<IContent> articles = myContext.GetArticles();
```

If you are stuck with .NET 3.5 you can just use Linq `Cast<T>()`:

```
IEnumerable<IContent> articles = myContext.GetArticles().Cast<IContent>();
```